# Creating and sharing python packages across the file system

Tags: python, package

Apologies if this is a duplicate, but I spent over an hour trying to find the specific answer to this question and couldn't find anything doing specifically what I want to do. The core problem I'm trying to solve is I'm writing code in /filepath/[myid]/lots/more/folders/something.py and teamates will be working in /filepath/[theirid]/lots/more/folders/something.py. I want to be able to create shared packages so that we can create shared functions that we can then run regularly in our own programs in very different locations.

The one thing I tried based on some answers was as a test on my personal windows computer I created a folder called test_package in my C: directory. Inside it there is is an empty file `__init.py__` and test.py which contains my test function. I tried:

```
from C import test_package
```

and it did not recognize the module C.

This would not be acceptable as a solution but I also attempted the relative path suggested by many articles:

```
from ........ import test_package
```

But it mentions that going above the current python package, which is kind of the point. I'm not looking to use code I've written in the same package, but to share work across the team to other people performing similar tasks but potentially completely different projects.

I've worked in R previously and it was relatively easy to create and share packages and simply host them in a team-level folder for members across the team to import. Does something like this exist in python? If not what is the preferred method to solve this problem? I don't know if this matters but most of the work would be using jupyter notebooks.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you will probably need to change the `sys.path` to a server, how to do that, i'm not sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find your sitepackage folder

my case `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages`

create a file with name my_test_package.py in there

```
def test():
    print('test worked!!!')
```

create your file anywhere

```
from my_test_package import test
test()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work in same directory

```
from filename import functionname/classname
```

If you work in above directory  with `__init_.py` inside directory

```
from directoryname.filename import functionname/classname
```

If you want work from any where copy file to site-packages and

```
from filename import functionname/classname
```

Comment: We don't work in the same directory, just the same file system. Can we use specific examples? I created a folder C:\test_package and in it is an `__init.py__` and test.py which has a function. If I want to use it in C:\folder1\folder2\project_name\project.py what would I put at the top of my file to import the function in test.py?